# Como Manter Iframe Auto-ajustável à Celular?

Tags: java, html, android

Preciso de Ajuda.

Sempre me recorro à ajuda aqui quando preciso de ajuda em geral, mas não achei resposta, e nada que funciona-se.

Preciso criar um endereço amigável - index, que chame uma página muito extensa num frame. o problema é que quando abro só o endereço extenso, ele se auto-ajusta certinho,  tudo lindo, mas no frame, ele aparece em pagina inteira.

Exemplo do Meu Index - (que não deve aparecer, é vazio, invisível + Página Abaixo.)

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <frame src="title.html">
    <frameset rows="0,*"BORDER=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0> 
        <frame src="menu.html">
        <frame src="https://www.restaurantlogin.com/ordering/restaurant/menu?company_uid=5ae31451-e048-4713-af53-3a1f9c5d738a">  
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

O Link que é auto ajustável é o seguinte - https://www.restaurantlogin.com/ordering/restaurant/menu?company_uid=5ae31451-e048-4713-af53-3a1f9c5d738a

Já tentei diversos ajustes.

Comment: Hj em dia não é recomendável o uso da tag iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual a sua real necessidade com o uso do iframe, só posso te antecipar que é bem chato trabalhar com eles.

Existem muitas restrições e problemas advindos do uso de iframe nas páginas.

A questão do tamanho é um problema bem comum, principalmente se a página do iframe trabalhar com renderização de elementos na tela via Javascript/Jquery. Todas as vezes que a página interna recebe uma atualização de tamanho a página externa que possui o iframe teria que fazer a atualização do tamanho do iframe.

Outro problema nos tamanhos é na tela que possui o iframe, se o usuário abrir a página no computador e alterar o tamanho da janela você terá que recalcular o tamanho do iframe.

Verifique se é possível fazer sua solução sem utilizar iframe.

Se mesmo assim deseja trabalhar com iframes, segue o exemplo baseado no seu código utilizando o iframe para ajustar ao tamanho da tela.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>
        html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="content" src="https://www.restaurantlogin.com/ordering/restaurant/menu?company_uid=5ae31451-e048-4713-af53-3a1f9c5d738a">
        </iframe>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    window.onload = (event) => {
        var widthPage = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
        var heightPage = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

        document.getElementById('content').style.height = heightPage + "px";
        document.getElementById('content').style.width = widthPage + "px";
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Rafael, Obrigado pelos comentários, vou ver se o código ajuda.

Na verdade, a idéia e simples, abrir este endereço aí, embutido no meu site. Criarei uma página com  CMS e nesa estarão listados varios estabelecimentos que dou suporte, assim clicando, vai abrir o link, sem contudo, precisar haver um botão que a pessoa tem que clicar.  hoje, a  gente clica num botão e o frame se abre, o ideal é clicar no link e mandar direto....

Desde já, obrigado, e  testado o Código, volto aqui dar retorno.